# Can you wear a cloak of charisma and a shadow veil at the same time?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

The *Libris Mortis* description of the *shadow veil* item (p76) says it precludes wearing any other kind of armor. Does this include a *cloak of charisma* or is a cloak not considered a kind of armor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *shadow veil* is a robe-slot item, which interferes with magic armor but not with shoulder-slot items like *cloak of charisma*. Note its presence in the **Undead Armor** section of *Libris Mortis*. See [Magic Items on the Body](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemBasics.htm#magicItemsOnTheBody) for more information on the various slots and how they are filled:

> Many magic items need to be donned by a character who wants to employ them or benefit from their abilities. It’s possible for a creature with a humanoid-shaped body to wear as many as twelve magic items at the same time. However, each of those items must be worn on (or over) a particular part of the body.
>
> A humanoid-shaped body can be decked out in magic gear consisting of one item from each of the following groups, keyed to which place on the body the item is worn.
>
> - One headband, hat, helmet, or phylactery on the head
> - One pair of eye lenses or goggles on or over the eyes
> - One amulet, brooch, medallion, necklace, periapt, or scarab around the neck
> - One vest, vestment, or shirt on the torso
> - **One robe or suit of armor on the body (over a vest, vestment, or shirt)**
> - One belt around the waist (over a robe or suit of armor)
> - **One cloak, cape, or mantle around the shoulders (over a robe or suit of armor)**
> - One pair of bracers or bracelets on the arms or wrists
> - One glove, pair of gloves, or pair of gauntlets on the hands
> - One ring on each hand (or two rings on one hand)
> - One pair of boots or shoes on the feet
>
> Of course, a character may carry or possess as many items of the same type as he wishes. However, additional items beyond those listed above have no effect.
>
> Some items can be worn or carried without taking up space on a character’s body. The description of an item indicates when an item has this property.

**Emphases** mine—notice how a robe or armor is separate from a cloak or a cape.

Furthermore, there are rules for combining magical items so that they can be used at the same time. This usually incurs a price premium of 50% for each effect after the first, but *Magic Item Compendium* specifies that certain bonuses—including enhancement bonuses to Charisma, as found on the *cloak of charisma*—can be combined with other items at no extra premium, just the sum of the two costs.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, be aware that D&D 3.5e has a thing called item slots. Only the first magical item worn in each slot works.

The three slots for what you would call the torso in plain language are the Shoulder slot (cloaks and capes), the Torso slot (vests and the like) and the Body slot (armors and most robes you wear over a vest, including the *Veil*).

Armors are worn over the whole body, and this prevents you from using two armors at the same time, but due to how item slots work it could still be possible to wear a nonmagical armor (still providing a bonus to your AC) and the *Veil* at the same time, weren't it for the wording of the *Veil* specifically preventing it. Basically, the authors want you to make a choice between AC and the benefits of the *Veil*.

Now that you can see that the wording is only there for enforcing some regulations over the Body slot, it goes without saying that no, **it does not interfere in any way with the cloak you want to use.**

Comment: (While I know that's largely inconsequential to this answer's accuracy, is it *really* the *first* worn magic item in any slot that has an effect? I thought it was, instead, the *last* worn magic item in a slot. For example, I thought that a *second* magic amulet donned after the first magic amulet obviates the *first* magic amulet rather than the first magic amulet obviating the second!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan It's the first item; If it was the last, it'd be an easy way to remove cursed magic items. That said, there is a rarely-used exploit where you can quickly change which magic rings you count as wearing by taking off rings you put on earlier.

Comment: @GMJoe That… makes a lot of sense, actually, but I'd still like a citation from somewhere to reassure me of it. ([Some cursed magic items can just be removed](https://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicItemsICA.html#amulet-of-inescapable-location) once the wearer realizes the cursed item's effect, though you're right that [most can't](https://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicItemsICA.html#boots-of-dancing). But a typical biped'll be awfully uncomfortable wearing two pairs of even magic boots!)

Comment: @HeyICanChan On page 214 of the *DMG*, under "Magic Items on the Body;" you'll find a reference in the second-last paragraph in that section. It's also on page 218 of the *Magic Item Compendium*, under "Body Slots;" It's the last sentence of the first paragraph after the list of slots and what can be worn on them.